# What is difference of 'bash' and '-bash'?

Tags: bash

When I run the `ps -f` command on Linux, the output shows 'bash' and '-bash'. I think there must be some diffrence between them. Is there someone can explain it, especially '-bash'? What is the meaning of the leading hyphen?

Comment: `-bash` denotes a login shell.

Comment: @yimlu : When you invoke a command, you can, if you want, give the command a different 'name' just for this single invocation. When you make `bash` believe that its name is `-bash`, it acts as a login shell, i.e. as if it were invoked by `bash -l`. The same effect can be achieved when you create a symlink `-bash` pointing to `bash`, and run it via the symlink.